# What is preventing a win here

Tags: riichi-mahjong

I'm playing Yakuza Kiwami 2 which has a Mahjong parlor to play in. I would have assumed the 5 I drew completed my hand.

- 2, 3, 4 of numbers
- triplets of 5 of numbers
- 6, 7, 8 of bamboo
- pair of 2 of stones

what's the reason it didn't? I'm assuming it has something to do with my hand being open.

[image]

Comment: You have two Chows.  Many versions of the game only permit one Chow in a completed hand.  Have you checked the local rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hand has a proper form, but it's missing a *yaku*, so it has no value to win with. You need at least one yaku to win with a hand.
Here are what are counted as [yakus in Yakuza games](https://yakuza.fandom.com/wiki/Mahjong#Common_Yaku).

Basically, that called triplet of 9s in numbers (which is still counted as being part of your hand), is ruining everything.
It's ruining Tanyao, or All Simples, since 9s aren't simples.
It's ruining Pinfu, or No-Points Hand, since it's a triplet and called (through, so does the triplet of 5s)
It's even ruining Tsumo, since you can only score with that, if your hand is closed, ie. no called sets.